# Schedule multiple changes for publishing at a given date

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm doing some research on CMS alternatives for a client.

One requisite is to allow content editors to schedule the publishing of multiple pages at a given date. Is it possible in **Umbraco**?

I can see that content editors can schedule each of the pages to be published at the same time. But what if they want to change the date for the whole set being published? **Can they do it without manually changing the "Publish At" value of a ALL the pages in the set?**

If this is not supported out of the box, do you know if Courier supports it? (Or any other add-on?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, you have to set the dates for each bit of content that you want to publish on schedule. There is no support for publishing "sets" of content.

Courier wouldn't be able to do this for you either, as that's fired manually.

Umbraco DOES have a lot of pretty easy to use extension points, so it's possible that you could write your own code to do this without too much trouble.

Comment: Pretty straightforward indeed: Custom datetime property +  a scheduled task that calls ContentService.PublishWithChildrenWithStatus(IContent content, [int userId = 0], [bool includeUnpublished = false])